# How to set a value at specified address in an elf file

Tags: gdb, elf, msys2, cortex-m, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I have a project for a cortex M4 microcontroller, which compiles and runs fine.
I'd like to add the checksum of the file to the file itself, so I can check the correctness of the binary at runtime.

The address where the checksum needs to be in the flash memory is set to a fixed address (0x08040000) in the linker configuration. At compile time the value is set to 0.
After linking i calculate the checksum of the binary and store it at this fixed address in the elf file.
That's the idea.

The debugger needs an elf file for debugging, so I need to set the value in the elf file. Setting it in the bin would be rather easy.

From an old source (which I suppose worked years ago) I found:

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb --write "program.elf" -batch -ex "set { unsigned long} 0x8040000 = 2269382981"
```

Where 2269382981 ist the calculated checksum.
There is no output if I execute the line above from the powershell.

However it does not work with `msys2 Packet mingw-w64-x86_64-arm-none-eabi-gdb 9.2-6` as
readelf shows.

```
c:\>readelf -x.BinaryInfo .\program.elf
Hex dump of section '.BinaryInfo':
  0x08040000 00000000 04000408 47770508          ........Gw..
```

How can I set a value in an elf file?

How can I get gdb to give gd to give some kind of error message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My Version of arm-none-eabi-gdb is obviously broken, even

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
```

gives no response.
I installed it via pacman from the msys2 shell.

But I figured I dont need an ARM version of GDB to edit the elf file.
So I just use

```
gdb --write "program.elf" -batch -ex "set { unsigned long} 0x8040000 = 2269382981"
```

which sets the value correctly.

**Edit:**
Bug reported to:
https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/16387